# failed to commit in master branch

Tags: github

I added a file into master branch (commit) and when I wanted to add another file: it says

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/XXXX/helloWorld.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I really have this problem and I do not the logic behind it. Could sb please tell me why I see this problem and what I should do?

Thanks

Comment: It says to do a pull before pushing again.  Have you tried that?

Comment: yes I did it, but with no success

Comment: With what message?  With no success can mean quite a few things.  Any feedback from the program? Did you encounter a conflict?

Answer (score 0):

You tried to push changes a branch that was not strictly in front of the origin branch.

```
Local:   A -> B -> C
Remote:  A -> B -> D
```

You will need to pull the remote changes (as instructed by the error message). If that merges ok, you can then push